# How to block Alamofire from encoding of query parameter

Tags: ios

I have Url Like :

`https://baseUrl/v2/orders/bookings?ourl=411093%7cMdTal8dUR6xpXXpzOiGgD1hRFnOyAHeo0Om9HeuB4Mk%3d`

I use Alamofire like: I'm Creating a custom Enum Class to get `URLRequestConvertible` parameter and that parameter i'm passing to alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(HotelBookingConfirmationRouter.get(orderUrl))
        .responseObject{(response: DataResponse<HotelBookingConfirmation>) in }

enum HotelBookingConfirmationRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

case get(String)

public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

    var method: HTTPMethod {

        return .get
    }

    let url: URL = {

        let url = URL(string: RBHWebServiceConfiguration.endpoint())!

        return url.appendingPathComponent(HotelAPI.bookingConfirmation)
    }()

    let params: ([String: String]) = {

        switch self {
        case .get(let ticketUrl):

            var dict = ["" : ""]
            dict = [ "ourl" :   ticketUrl]
            return dict
        }
    }()

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.setValue("MOBILE_APP", forHTTPHeaderField: "channel_name")

    let encoding                = URLEncoding.queryString
    var encodedRequest          = try! encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
    encodedRequest.httpMethod       = method.rawValue
    encodedRequest.timeoutInterval  = 30

    return encodedRequest
}
}
```

Logging the request, I receive:

`https://baseUrl/v2/orders/bookings?ourl= 411093%2547cMdTal8dUR6xpXXpzOiGgD1hRFnOyAHeo0Om9HeuB4Mk%3d`

query string is encoding i.e "2547" instead "7cM"

But, I need to remain with same parameter can anyone help me please to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a '%' character in your query value, when you percent encode that, it will be replaced with '%25'.

You can find more info here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

My suggestion would be to try and get rid of the % character, if you can't do that, simply construct your URL manually.

Have a nice day :)
Dejan.